# Table View con altura de celdas diferentes y ajustables a su contenido

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Estoy intentando hacer una vista que contenga un `TableView` con diferentes celdas de diferentes alturas que se ajusten a su contenido. Pero no encuentro ningún ejemplo que funcione bien.

Lo que hago es implementar un `tableView` con un prototipo de celda a la que no le declaro altura. Voy rellenando contenido con un `collectionView` con diferentes items que si sobrepasan el total del ancho  de la celda del `tableView` haga un salto a la siguiente linea con un `scrollVertical`.

Añado el siguiente código al `viewDidLoad()` para que haga un reajuste vertical de la celda pero no funciona:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: al collection view que metes dentro de cada celda le estás dando una altura fija y lo estás fijando a los márgenes top y bottom de la celda?

Comment: El collection view no le he puesto altura fija ni tampoco le he puesto bottom y top

Comment: Para poder usar automaticDimension necesitas que los elementos de la celda estén referenciados a su contenedor (en los 4 márgenes), si no... no puede saber el contenido en su interior, ni puede calcularlo

Comment: Sabes de algún enlace donde pueda ver un ejemplo? Actualmente tengo una celda TableViewCell con un collectionView interior, este CollectionView tiene varias celdas CollectionViewCell con un ScrollVertical. Necesito que al hacer el ScrollVertical la altura de la Celda del TableviewCell se agrande tanto como el ScrollView para que se vea el total del contenido del CollectionView

Answer (score 2):

Para entender como funciona `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` este tutorial explica lo básico bastante bien: https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Respecto a meter un `collectionview` dentro de una celda de un `tableview` a priori diría que no es la mejor solución. Si además los elementos están colocados con un scroll vertical, al final suena a que necesitas meter más elementos en tu tableview. Podrías hacer uso de las `sections`, para meter un número variable de elementos según la sección en la que estés (al final los **x** elementos que meterías en tu `collectionview` pasarían a ser **x**  `tableviewCell` en cada `seccion`).

Si a pesar de todo quieres seguir con tu enfoque, creo lo que necesitarás es calcular el número de elementos que contendrá tu `collectionview`, y la altura que suman entre todos, para asignarle esa altura a tu `collectionview` y bloquear el scroll de tu `collectionview`.

`collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false`

Por último, tendrás que añadir constraints a tu `colectionView` para referenciarlo al `top` y `bottom` de tu `tableviewCell`, para que esta sepa calcular su altura (tal y como te explicará el tutorial)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda